# Prepending flow-operations to a Sink

Tags: akka-stream

I have a Source that I need to transform into another. Along the way I also want to tap into the stream and send it to a Sink. That works okay with alsoTo and wireTap.

However, I want to do additional transformations on the data before it reaches the sink:

```
Source ---> map ---> scan ---> map ---> return as Source
                           \
                            \ alsoTo
                             \
                              \ ---> map --> Sink
```

In the docs, I read:

> It is possible to attach a Flow to a Source resulting in a composite
>   source, and it is also possible to prepend a Flow to a Sink to get a
>   new sink.

But, I couldn't find an example to prepened such a Flow to a Sink, e.g. execute a "map" operation before forwarding to the Sink.

VERY simplified example:

```
val sink = Sink.foreach(println)
val source = Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val transformed_source = source.map(n => n * 10).alsoTo(sink).map(n => n + 1)

// but I want something along the lines of
alsoTo(map(n => "The result is " + n) ~> sink)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Flow.to is what I am looking for.

```
def to[Mat2](sink: Graph[SinkShape[Out], Mat2]): Sink[In, Mat]
```

> Connect this Flow to a Sink, concatenating the processing steps of
>   both.